# Parsing and POS tagging in French under Python 3.6 and Stanford CoreNLP 3.9.1

Tags: python, stanford-nlp

Has anyone the experience to adapt the following (3.6) Python code to get a POS tagging in French rather than English:

```
# *** POS tagging *** with CoreNLP
from nltk.tag.stanford import CoreNLPPOSTagger
CoreNLPPOSTagger(url='http://localhost:9000').tag('What is the airspeed of an unladen swallow ?'.split())
```

Similary, for the parsing:

```
# *** Parsing *** with CoreNLP
from nltk.parse.corenlp import CoreNLPParser
stanford_parser = CoreNLPParser()
json_result = stanford_parser.api_call('He is fine')
for sentence in json_result['sentences']:
    for token in sentence['tokens']:
        print(token)
```

All this code runs smoothly.

Thank you for your help.

L.